# filename extract in batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

i have a requirement where i have files starting with say :- M8585858 and UM966696. I have already written a code to read these files using the for loop  like the one below :-

```
cd C:\Input\

echo M files ..........
for %%f in (M*.*) do (
   rem echo %%~nfAPSI
    set v=%%~nfAPSI
)
echo %v%

echo UM files ..........
for %%f in (UM*.*) do (
    set v=%%~nfAPSI
    )
set "v=%v:~1%"
echo %v%
cd D:\usr\src\IN\
cd
echo Directory changed
echo File in the input directory
timeout 5
echo Enumerating files before copy..
dir C:\In
java.exe -jar C:\abc.jar -rc4 -crypt C:\Input\ C:\Output\ %v%
Echo Enumerating files after copy.....
dir C:\Out
echo End Of Batch File Execution
```

but now what happens is whenever a file with M966696 is dropped into the input folder C:\Input\ , the batch file deletes the first character 'M' and reads with 966696 ( which is incorrect ). i need to send the entire filename as public key. So, basically i am using the loops one below the other without conditions. Hence when it comes to the second loop, it deletes the first character. 
So, the ideal workaround is to include a condition with both M* and UM* related files. I tried using FINDSTR but it is not working or maybe I am not using it correctly - can anyone tell me how to use the if-else condition around the loops for the loops to run based on filenames?

Comment: Is there more to your code? I am unable to replicate your problem: http://i.imgur.com/Ckw2UsW.png Please ensure that the code you provide is [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry - let me format it

Comment: as you can see, multi-line code doesn't display properly in comments. Please add it to your original question.

Comment: ohh! - thank you very much for being so cooperative!

Comment: The line `"v=%v:~1%"` is what is removing the first character. Right now, it's being run on every file it encounters because it's not inside of any conditions or loops. If you just need to remove the U from UM files, move that line up one to inside of the for loop that processes UM files.

Comment: yes exactly! - so the requirement is as i mentioned in my original post - Basically i am using the loops one below the other without conditions. Hence when it comes to the second loop, it deletes the first character(that is also a requirement). So, the ideal workaround is to include a condition with both M* and UM* related files/filenames. I tried using FINDSTR but it is not working or maybe I am not using it correctly - need to know how to use the if-else with the filename - that'll do i guess?

Comment: It's not deleting the character in the second loop, it's deleting the character _after_ the second loop, regardless of whether or not the file would be processed in that loop. Are you just trying to remove the U from UM files?

Comment: yes it is deleting after the second loop only. yes I am trying to remove U from the UM files. That is a part of a requirement and just pass the filename M*APSI without extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line to remove the first character of UM filenames is in the wrong place. You need to move it inside of the for loop that processes the UM files. And since you need to set and manipulate variables inside of `for` loops, you will also need to enable delayed expansion.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd C:\Input\

echo M files ..........
for %%f in (M*.*) do (
    set v=%%~nfAPSI
)
echo !v!

echo UM files ..........
for %%f in (UM*.*) do (
    set v=%%~nfAPSI
    set "v=!v:~1!"
)
echo !v!
```

Comment: ok. let me try this - how i use the variable v with - java.exe -jar C:\abc.jar -rc4 -crypt C:\Input\ C:\Output\ **%v%** <- OR -> java.exe -jar C:\abc.jar -rc4 -crypt C:\Input\ C:\Output\ **!v!**

Comment: Use the variable v like `!v!`. And the first loop will _only_ process files whose first character is M, while the second loop will _only_ process files whose first two characters are UM.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are babling about.

Always use full paths. Especially if you want to ask for help.

```
for %A in (c:\input\um*.* c:\input\m*.*) do echo %A
```

Comment: babbling about? - i think u have a basic understanding problem - pls refrain from replying if you haven't understood the requirement!

Comment: @bleedblue - you didn't use code formatting when listing your code, so your post was very hard to follow.

Comment: i am sorry - code formatting - i will check how to do it. Sorry about that. new to this community. will keep it in mind from next time. thank you.

Comment: AndI showed how to do in one loop. Which was the only thing I understood in your question.

Comment: The first line of the code was to `cd` into C:\input, so the full path really isn't necessary, though I agree, it's a practice that should be encouraged. Secondly, `%A` for the command line, `%%A` for scripts.

Comment: If the folder doesn't exist you'll run commands on wrong files. CD is for interactive use where it's very useful. CD is part of my campaign against voodoo programming.

Comment: the folder will exist - no doubt about that. CD i used because - I will be sure that i am in the correct directory. I actually replicated the steps first on command prompt. I thought it would be a good practice to do the same thing while writing the script. I am also creating a log file when the file gets encrypted on the output folder hence using **echo** with the steps.